# Multiple counters for figures and sections using CSS

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to implement multiple counters in a html file for separate classes?  can to my knowledge only count one thing, and is too primitive for this.

As an example, would it be possible to let the following code ...

HTML:

```
<div class="section">section title</div>
ipsum lorem
<span class="image">image title</span>
<img src="example.com/img.jpg">
ipsum lorem
ipsum lorem
<span class="image">another image title</span>
<img src="example.com/another_img.jpg">
<div class="section">another section title</div>
ipsum lorem
<span class="image">yet another image title</span>
<img src="example.com/yet_another_img.jpg">
```

... automatically count the number of figures, sections (or possibly more stuff), and display on the page like this:

section 1: section title
ipsum lorem
image 1: image title
 _ _
| o ¦
ipsum lorem
ipsum lorem
image 2: another image title
 _ _
| \ ¦
section 1: another section title
ipsum lorem
image 3: yet another image title
 _ _
| [] ¦

Comment: Of course it is possible. And if you Google stuff like "css multiple counters" or similar, you should be able to find examples that explain how its done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like:

```
.section { counter-increment: section-counter; }
.section:before { content: 'Section ' counter(section-counter) ': '; }

.image { counter-increment: image-counter; }
.image:before { content: 'Image ' counter(image-counter) ': '; }
```